# Response over HTTP Protocol

Tags: response, stateless

how a web server respond to the right client over HTTP as HTTP is a stateless Protocol. i mean to say that there would be multiple request and response at web server, and a client get its respective response.

Answer (score 0):

During the process of a single http request a socket connection is kept open (if none of the endpoints abandon in that period of time).

The stateless term means that between multiple requests from the same client the protocol alone doesn't do anything for you to keep track of any state.